# Design error SwipeRefreshLayout v4 - Pull to refresh

Tags: android

I'm currently making an app with a web service, and for that reason it needs to be always updated, so I try to apply Pull to refresh

My floating button disappears when I use SwipeRefreshLayout v4

SwipeRefreshLayout v4

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
    ...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reciclador"
        ..../>

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />   

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And this is when I did not implement it

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
    ....>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/reciclador"
        ... />

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />   

</RelativeLayout>
```

before

[image]

after

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SwipeRefreshLayout` should  contain only one child(`ListView`, `RecyclerView`, etc.) to work properly.

You should move `FloatingActionButton` from `SwipeRefreshLayout` to your `RelativeLayout`. This should help.

Final layout markup should look like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_main"
    ....>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ... >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/reciclador"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            ... />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ... />   

</RelativeLayout>
```